# Can Xcode fold multiple methods at once, as a set?

Tags: xcode4.5, code-folding

I have about two thousand lines of code in my class and near fifty methods inside. I know I can divide them by `#pragma mark SomeMethodsSet` and see that listed in the jump bar above, but is there some way to **fold** up each set together, the way I can for single methods?

Comment: Holy moly.  It sounds like you may need some subclasses, or at least some categories.

Comment: Sounds good, but it's useful not only for such big classes!

Answer (score 4):

Command + Option + Shift + Left Arrow - folds all methods
Command + Option + Shift + Right Arrow - unfolds all methods

Answer (score 1):

If you hover your mouse between the place where you set a breakpoint, and the place where you write the code, you'll see an arrow pointing down. Clicking on it will hide the code.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: K.O. =) But I want to hide not only one method, I want to do hide several methods in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Xcode jump bar magic for better navigation through your code -> http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-4-jump-bar-tips-and-tricks.html

If you find yourself struggling with large classes and a huge count of methods, why aren't you try to refactor your code? Split the one big class in several smaller ones. Extract some logic  into new classes. Try to keep classes small and let them only do few things at once. Avoid 'god classes', which try to solve all problems at once.